# jquery - can't get the elements to fadeOut / fadeIn

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've wrote this code in order to replace the text regarding the img they are clicking.
I can't understand why my code isn't executing, I looked it over and over again.
I hope someone can find my mistake :(

This is the jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
            $('#text-1').fadeIn(500);
            //click event
            $('.img').click(function() {
                var currentId = $(this).attr('id');
                alert(currentId);
                if (currentId===3) {
                    $('#text-3').fadeIn('fast');
                    $('#text-2, #text-1').css('display', 'none');
                } else if (currentId===2) {
                    $('#text-2').fadeIn('fast');
                    $('#text-1, #text-3').css('display', 'none');
                } else if (currentId===1) {
                    $('#text-2').fadeIn('fast');
                    $('#text-1, #text-3').css('display', 'none');
                }
            });
        });
```

and this is the HTML:

```
<div>
        <div id="icon">
            <a id="1" class="img" href=""><img style="background: url(http://images.webydo.com/10/100459/169860/hutim.jpg) 0 0;" src="" /></a>
            <a id="2" class="img" href=""><img style="background: url(http://images.webydo.com/10/100459/Folder%201/work_electric_main_banner.png) -20px -10px;" src="" /></a>
            <a id="3" class="img" href=""><img src="http://hviil.co.il/wp-content/uploads/2013/02/DS-2CD7254F-EIZ-310x310.jpg" alt="מצלמות אבטחה" /></a>
        </div>
        <div id="text">
            <div id="text-1" class="textbox">
                <h2>1</h2>
                <p>adssssssssssssssssssssssasdsaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</p>
            <div id="text-2" class="textbox">
                <h2>2</h2>
                <p>adssssssssssssssssssssssasdsaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</p>
            </div>
            <div id="text-3" class="textbox">
                <h2>3</h2>
                <p>adssssssssssssssssssssssasdsaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Please help!!!!
Thanks

Comment: did you added the reference jquery ?

Comment: As per here, I tested and when clicking on the Image it is going to the third div

Comment: I tested your code and it's alert the third div

Comment: your currentId is string and you are comparing it to number strictly. You should use == instead

Comment: I think also you need return false at the end of your function to stop the page reloading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTML

```
<div>
   <div id="icon">
            <a id="1" class="img" href=""><img style="background: url(http://images.webydo.com/10/100459/169860/hutim.jpg) 0 0;" src="" /></a>
            <a id="2" class="img" href=""><img style="background: url(http://images.webydo.com/10/100459/Folder%201/work_electric_main_banner.png) -20px -10px;" src="" /></a>
            <a id="3" class="img" href=""><img src="http://hviil.co.il/wp-content/uploads/2013/02/DS-2CD7254F-EIZ-310x310.jpg" alt="מצלמות אבטחה" /></a>
        </div>
        <div id="text">
            <div id="text-1" class="textbox">
                <h2>1</h2>
                <p>adssssssssssssssssssssssasdsaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</p>
            <div id="text-2" class="textbox">
                <h2>2</h2>
                <p>adssssssssssssssssssssssasdsaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</p>
            </div>
            <div id="text-3" class="textbox">
                <h2>3</h2>
                <p>adssssssssssssssssssssssasdsaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {
            $('#text-1').fadeIn(500);
            //click event
            $('.img').click(function() {
                var currentId = $(this).attr('id');
                alert(currentId);
                if (currentId==3) {
                    $('#text-3').fadeIn('fast');
                    $('#text-2, #text-1').css('display', 'none');
                } else if (currentId==2) {
                    $('#text-2').fadeIn('fast');
                    $('#text-1, #text-3').css('display', 'none');
                } else if (currentId==1) {
                    $('#text-2').fadeIn('fast');
                    $('#text-1, #text-3').css('display', 'none');
                }
            });
        });
```

WORKING LINK
http://jsbin.com/heseforaxe/1/edit?html,js,output

Answer (score 1):

Problem is in your condition checking

instead of using such that

`currentId===3` // checks that currentId is numeric 3

Use

`currentId=='3'` //changed === to ==, check that currentId is string type 3

And one more thing, after clicking `a` your page is redirecting, so if you want to prevent this, use `preventDeault` or put `#` in your `href`.

Comment: Also there should be preventDefault on `a`

Comment: @Mateusz Nowak yes there should be preventDefault or put `#` in `href`

Answer (score 0):

> var currentId = $(this).attr('id');

All the value of attributes is string ,not number.
so,you can change like this.

> currentId==="3";

or

> currentId==3;

Answer (score 0):

> 1. currentId===3 this should be changed to currentId==3 because the returned id is string
> 2. because there is a post back when clicking the link you need to add ref="#" to the a tag
> 3. there are missing closing tags on div id='text-1' and the main div
> 4. you can find a working copy of this from this url "http://jsfiddle.net/t3L1fkuh/6/" (i have removed     the images because 2 of them does not load).

```
.textbox{
     display: none;    
   }
```

> the above class is added so that it adds the fade in effect on page load